# Evict 2nd level cache items Syscache/Nhibernate

Tags: c#, caching, nhibernate, evict, syscache

I am using NHibernate 3.3 with Syscache 2nd level cache and I am trying to evict an object from the 2nd level cache, but it doesn't seem to work.

I am using this code based on other examples:

```
var CollectionCache = NHibernateSessionFactory.Instance.GetAllCollectionMetadata();
var ClassCache = NhibernateSessionFactory.Instance.GetAllClassMetadata();
NhibernateSessionFactory.Instance.EvictQueries();
foreach (var collectionMetadata in NhibernateSessionFactory.Instance.GetAllCollectionMetadata())
         NhibernateSessionFactory.Instance.EvictCollection(collectionMetadata.Key);
foreach (var classMetadata in NhibernateSessionFactory.Instance.GetAllClassMetadata())
         NhibernateSessionFactory.Instance.EvictEntity(classMetadata.Key);
```

After evicting, the CollectionCache and ClassCache still have the same number of items.

Also, `NhibernateSessionFactory.Instance.Evict(typeof(someObject), SomeObjectId);` does not seem to have any effect.

My use case: I am working with detached objects, and when another application makes changes to the database, I need to evict those items from the 2nd level cache to keep in it in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Clear 2-level cache nHibernate (this method worked for me):

```
 private void ClearCache()
    {
        _repositoryFactory.GetSession().Clear();
        var sf = _repositoryFactory.GetSession().SessionFactory;
        sf.EvictQueries();
        foreach (var collectionMetadata in sf.GetAllCollectionMetadata())
            sf.EvictCollection(collectionMetadata.Key);
        foreach (var classMetadata in sf.GetAllClassMetadata())
            sf.EvictEntity(classMetadata.Key);
    }
```